# Import a CSV or JSON file into MySQL

Tags: mysql-workbench

i have csv file converted to json format and was trying to import it in MySQL Workbench.

[image: importing screen], however while browsing the image even if it was "(.json)" format it was not available to browse.

Answer (score 0):

You used the wrong area in MySQL Workbench. This part of the admin section is used to import MySQL dumps, text files that contain SQL statements.

What you need instead is the import wizard:

[image]

which allows you to select a CSV or JSON file to be imported.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response it was of great help. Further how to use that database which is imported in the mysql

Comment: It does not help importing data though often.
It shows success but data does not get imported.